# Smooth-plotter and connectSeparatedPoints incompatible?

Tags: dygraphs

I am successful in using **smooth-plotter.js** in dygraphs to, well, smooth the plot. However, when I have a data set with gaps, it's either "smooth with gaps" (ignoring **connectSeparatedPoints**) or switching off the smoothing, at which point **connectSeparatedPoints** starts working again, but I'm back with a spiky graph.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this how it is supposed to be? I have been trying out a lot, with no success...

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, `smoothPlotter` does not support `connectSeparatedPoints`. Feel free to file an issue or, even better, [send a pull request](http://dygraphs.com/changes.html) to add it!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation - and while I have to read up on pull requests, I will probably do it, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

To get the data gaps to show in the right place for my data I had to continue the time series in the same sequence throughout the data gap and use NA in the data value. The data stops and start where it should without inferring a 'straight line jump' across the gap.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRFvN.jpg)